# No instance for (Eq TrafficLight) arising from a use of `elem' Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq TrafficLight)

Tags: haskell

I have an example from Learn You a Haskell for Great Good named

```
class Eq1 a where
   (===), (=/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
   x === y = not $ x =/= y
   x =/= y = not $ x === y  

data TrafficLight = Red | Yellow | Green  

instance Eq1 TrafficLight where  
    Red === Red = True  
    Green === Green = True  
    Yellow === Yellow = True  
    _ === _ = False  


instance Show TrafficLight where  
    show Red = "Red light"  
    show Yellow = "Yellow light"  
    show Green = "Green light"  


main = do
    print $ Red === Red
    print $ Red === Yellow 
    print $ [Red, Yellow, Green] 
    print $ Red `elem` [Red, Yellow, Green]
```

and the first three rows are work, but the last line contains `elem` doesn't, got an error:

```
 No instance for (Eq TrafficLight) arising from a use of `elem'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Eq TrafficLight)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `Red `elem` [Red, Yellow, Green]'
```

I look for the solution how can I add an instance for the marked part, but didn't find hints about the topic, I am new in Haskell so thanks in advance

Tamas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to provide your own `elem`. What is `elem`'s type?

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
```

However, your traffic light doesn't have an `Eq` instance. It has a `Eq1` instance.

You have to write your own `elem1`:

```
elem1 :: Eq1 a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem1 y xs = -- exercise
```